# Can't import fronted data for WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[Demo Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK5qE.png)

I'm trying to "Start Demo Installation" in WordPress theme but it takes so long time (as shown in the picture) without installation

Note: I'm using local WordPress

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue of upload files size can you try it again after increasing it

```
1. Function.php
 @ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );

2. php.ini
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300

3. .htacess
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Comment: Thanks! But where can i find php.ini file?

Comment: if you used localhost then go to wamp icon after it becomes green left click on it go to php->php.ini and for server just create new text file save name as php.ini

Comment: Still have the same issue :(

Comment: which theme are you using?